# New to arrays with C

Tags: c, arrays

I am making a loop and I want each time it enters the loop it will store my variable into a separate `array`.

Example: loop 1, variable stored in `i[1]`; loop 2, variable stored in `i[2]`; and so on.

```
for (i1 = 0; i1 < size; i1++)
{
    printf("%d ", i1);
    y1[] = i1;
}
```

Basically, apart from printing out `i1` I want `i1` to be stored in `array`s for later use.

Comment: ` it will store my variable into a seperate array` doesn't make any sense at all. Instead you wish to add the loop index to array use `y1[i1]=i1`.

Comment: please writing new question which is duplicate creates spam here... please search first and then post question like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int y1[size];

for (i1 = 0; i1 < size; i1++) {
        printf("%d ", i1);
        y1[i1] = i1;  // indexing 
}
```

Now it is stored in array `y1` for future use.

Comment: Oh god why everything must be so easy. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after `y1[size]`

Comment: I am sure I can figure that out